# Rank best/worst performers by absolute and relative values

Tags: sorting, tableau-api

Context: a company has two measures qualifying their performance on the ability to deliver their products (coverage). Wanting to assess the worst performing products, they look at:

- Uncovered Quantity (an absolute number - the number of items that will not be delivered on time)
- % Uncovered (relative % - basically Uncovered Quantity/Total Ordered Quantity)

One can then rank a list of products based on either measure. Uncovered Quantity:

**Product; Uncovered Qty; % Uncovered**

1. Product A; 10,000; 1%
2. Product B; 200; 2%
3. Product C; 100; 50%

Or based on % Uncovered:

1. Product C; 100; 50%
2. Product B; 200; 2%
3. Product A; 10,000; 1%

But the issue with both sorting methods is that they focus solely on one measure. For instance, Product C has a problematic coverage %, but this will not be stressed enough in the first sorting method. On the other hand, even though Product A's % Uncovered is alright, we might consider that 10,000 units is an issue. This will not be discovered using the second sorting method.

Is there a (mathematical) concept allowing to sort this data emphasizing the importance of both measures?

Comment: PS: This is a Tableau question, but just providing the required idea is sufficient. I posted this question in Stackoverflow because I noticed more Tableau questions in here.

Answer (score 1):

Make a scatter plot and you'll be able to see both measures at once.

To make a scatter plot of your data. First, put one measure on the row shelf (say percent uncovered) and one measure on the column shelf (say number uncovered). At that point, you'll see one mark on the pane aggregating all your data. Choose either sum or avg for your aggregation for each measure, I'd suggest average.

Then you need to group your data to see more than one aggregate point. To do that, either drag a discrete (blue) field onto the shelf to represent each block of data -- say product  or product type. Or you can turn off aggregation under the Analysis menu (at the risk of too much detail)

Comment: I kind of wanted to keep the data in a table, but this solution is certainly more suitable from a visual point of view. +1